# Why doesn't Sort work in this case ? (Only numerical values)

Tags: interpolation, sorting

**Context**

I want to interpolate a complicated symmetric function f of 2 variables x and y defined by some numerical integral involving Bessel functions. Since computing the integral itself is a bit long (~2 sec per evaluation) and I'm interested in a rather large range of values on the finest grid possible,  I only want to compute points for which y>=x and then use the symmetry to get the rest.

Let's for the sake of argument say that f[x,y] = x*y. I would like to interpolate some table that would look like

```
samp = 0.1; (*In practice samp is much smaller and max much higher but I wanted this to execute instantenously*)
max = 10;
WantedData=Table[{x,y,x*y},{x,0.001,max,samp},{y,0.001,max,samp}]//Flatten[#,1]&;
```

but what I compute is rather

```
ObtainedData=Table[{x,y,x*y},{x,0.001,max,samp},{y,x,max,samp}]//Flatten[#,1]&;
```

Nevertheless I can always reconstruct WantedData by doing

```
ObtainedData=ObtainedData//Transpose;

x=ObtainedData[[1]];
y=ObtainedData[[2]];
z=ObtainedData[[3]];

TransformedData=Sort[DeleteDuplicates[{Join[x,y],Join[y,x],Join[z,z]}//Transpose],(#1[[1]]<#2[[1]]&&(If[#1[[1]]==#2[[1]],#1[[2]]<#2[[2]]]))&];

(*I also tried with same issues:
TransformedData=Sort[DeleteDuplicates[{Join[x,y],Join[y,x],Join[z,z]}//Transpose]];
TransformedData=Sort[DeleteDuplicates[{Join[x,y],Join[y,x],Join[z,z]}//Transpose],Less];*)
```

where the use of the Sort function would re-organise everything so that Interpolation can then recognise this as a function computed on a structured grid.

**Issue**

However, If I now try to interpolate TransformedData

```
TransformedData //Interpolation;
```

I get the errors

```
Interpolation::udeg: "Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1."
Interpolation::femimq: "The element mesh has insufficient quality of \!\(\*RowBox[{\"-\", \"4.1023203976182984`*^-13\"}]\). A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements."
Interpolation::fememtlq: "The quality \!\(\*RowBox[{\"-\", \"4.1023203976182984`*^-13\"}]\) of the underlying mesh is too low. The quality needs to be larger than \!\(\*RowBox[{\"0.`\"}]\)."
```

**Attempt**

I think reducing the sampling (not what I want to do in my case) illustrates what goes wrong though it makes the warnings in Interpolation disappear (I guess because the list is now small enough so that it can work things out by itself ?). If I set samp = 5 then WantedData and TransformedData look like this

```
WantedData
Out= {{0.001, 0.001, 1.*10^-6}, {0.001, 5.001, 0.005001}, {5.001, 0.001, 0.005001}, {5.001, 5.001, 25.01}}

TransformedData
Out= {{0.001, 5.001, 0.005001}, {0.001, 0.001, 1.*10^-6}, {5.001, 0.001, 0.005001}, {5.001, 5.001, 25.01}}
```

where one can see that the Sort function did not quite work as I would have expected.

Moreover, I was under the impression reading the Sort documentation that it would re-arrange my list the way I want it without any options but it does not work either. Nor does using the option "Less" in the Sort command.

I know that many questions about Sort have been previously asked but since my issue does not seem to come from the nature of the objects I want to order, these are all triplets of approximate real numbers and adding //N everywhere does change anything, I can't see what the problem might be.

Do you have any idea what's happening here ?

I'm using Mathematica 11.3 on MacOS.

Comment: An idea would be to just compute the triangle of values you want, and then use `UpperTriangularize[]`/`LowerTriangularize[]` + `Transpose[]` to complete your table.